# Pythonic way of writing belongs function in two sets

Tags: python, set

I have two sets containing only strings, and I am trying to write a function like:

```
def belongs(setA, setB):
   return True/False
```

**Definition:** If a `set`, say `setB` has an item which contains (`string` contains) an item in `setA`,  then I call `setB` *belongs* to `setA`. Some examples:

```
setA = set(['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'])

set1 = set(['abcc', 'xyz', 'klm'])                   # does not belong to setA
set2 = set(['app', 'banaba', 'baba'])                # does not belong to setA
set3 = set(['apples', 'xyz'])                        # belongs to setA
set4 = set(['bananaaa', 'hello', 'world', 'stack'])  # belongs to setA
```

My current code:

```
def belongs(set1, set2):
    for i in set1:
        for j in set2:
            if i in j:
                return True
    return False
```

Is there a better/more Pythonic way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Is every string of `set1` a substring of every string of `set2`?

Comment: @dlask No. One is enough.

Comment: You might want to add *without using extra space*, because if I understand you correctly, you can simply *flatten* `setA` into a single set of items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the function:

```
def belongs(set1, set2):
    return any(s1 in s2 for s1 in set1 for s2 in set2)
```

And test it:

```
assert not belongs(setA, set1)
assert not belongs(setA, set2)
assert belongs(setA, set3)
assert belongs(setA, set4)
```

Comment: Cool fact: this is a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression), not a list comprehension, meaning it's just about as efficient as the original nested `for` loop. (These don't seem to be very well-known.)

Comment: @Mauris I don't speak about *list comprehension*. And the OP doesn't speak about *more efficient* version, just about *more pythonic* one.

Comment: Whoa, relax. I said "cool fact". Your answer is perfectly fine. Not a lot of people know about the advantages of generator expressions, so I wanted to assuage anyone's worries that this answer might have been slower than the original.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand now. Honestly it's a surprise for me to know that anyone would consider the generator expression *slower* than regular loops. Anyway, thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @dlask: isn't it reversed? OP wants `s1 in s2`

Comment: @dlask: unrelated: generator expressions *are* slower on CPython than ordinary loops i.e., the code in the question should be faster.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Measurements show that generator expressions are slower only in Python2, they seem to be faster in Python3.

Comment: @dlask: For the input in the question, the loop-based solution is faster than genexpr-based one on both Python 2 and 3 on my machine (Python 2.7, Python 3.4).

Answer (score 2):

The problem of checking whether any string from `setA` is a substring of any item in `setB` i.e., whether `setB` "belongs to" `setA` can be solved using `grep -F`.

`grep -Flf setA set1 set2 set3 set4` prints sets that "belong to" `setA` i.e., `set3`, `set4` in this case. The [Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) formed the basis of the original Unix command `fgrep`. It can be much more efficient for a large input than a naive solution with nested loops e.g., [from 20 hours for a brute-force approach down to a couple of minutes using `fgrep`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/383763/23044).

If you can't install 3rd party libraries; you could try `re` module, to improve performance if you need it:

```
import re
from itertools import imap

substrings = sorted(setA, key=len, reverse=True) # longest first
found = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, substrings))).search
print([any(imap(found, S)) for S in [set1, set2, set3, set4]])
# -> [False, False, True, True]
```